# Spark SQLContext does not find hive tables

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

i'm try to query an Hive table through a simple Spark Job (written in Java).

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("MyJob");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

DataFrame df = sqlContext.table("scf");
```

but when i submit the jar through **spark-submit**, i have the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.table(SQLContext.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.table(SQLContext.scala:827)
    at MyJob.myJob(MyJob.java:30)
    at MyJob.main(MyJob.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**I'm sure table exists**. If i run **sqlContext.table("scf").count** in the spark-shell, it gives me the result.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to register the table name "dcf", I guess.

Answer (score 2):

SQLContex doesn't support Hive. You have to use HiveContext or SparkSession with Hive enabled support.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.  Turned out spark-submit could not "find" the correct (or any, I assume) Hive environment.  I added my hive-site.xml to the "files" parameter of my spark-submit and it worked.

ex.
spark-submit 
  --master yarn 
  --deploy-mode cluster 
  --class  
  --files 
  ...